# Ajax render only if element exists

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have the following usecase: I have a button on the screen which rerenders an other element.

```
<h:commandButton value="button">
  <f:ajax  execute="@this" render="toBeRendered" />
</h:commandButton>
......
<h:outputPanel id="toBeRendered"/>
```

My problem is that this other element (toBeRendered) does not always exists because it is within an ui compostion on the page so JSF fails when it builds the view and can't find the element thats in the render attribute of the f:ajax tag. I know that this validation is no longer there in newer version of mojarra but updating is not an option. Does anybody has a workaround that so that it would only render when the other element exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`UIComponent#findComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent-java.lang.String-) to find it and then print its ID. If it can't be found, then `null` would be considered anyway.

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:ajax ... render="#{component.findComponent('toBeRendered').id}" />
</h:commandButton>
...
<h:panelGroup id="toBeRendered" />
```

Note that `#{component}` is an implicit EL object referring the current `UIComponent` instance. So the code is complete as-is.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, noted should be that the missing `<f:ajax>` validation in Mojarra 2.2.5+ will come back later as per [issue 1372](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1372). It's namely confusing to many starters.

Comment: Can't. The problem is that the button is in an outer "xhtml" and the element to be rendered is within an ui composition on that page.

Comment: You should have included that in the question. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry the question was not correct I updated it thanks for the help!