# p:ajax update of ID that doesn't exists

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces and I have a line:

```
<p:ajax update="toUpdate">
```

the problem is, that this ID not always exists on the page.
( the page is dynamic and sometimes it contains a part that have this specific ID and sometimes not)
 When it exists, it works great, but when the ID doesn't exist, the component crash - (probably it's some validation issue)

How can I fix it?

Is it a well known issue?

Thanks!

Comment: what did you mea *ID doesn't exist*?

Comment: can you explain also *ID is dynamic and not always exists* ?

Comment: @YCF_L Sorry. I updated it. does it clear now?

Comment: mmm can you please share some code this still not clear :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812018/ajax-render-only-if-element-exists this is a similar question. The answer didn't work for. (I'm not the PrimeFaces makes a difference)

Comment: Why not **not** render the `p:ajax` if the component it refers to is also no rendered...

Comment: Try to update the parent of the element that doesn't exist in some cases (go to parent as needed to the "static" parent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an always rendered component to update, for example:

```
<p:ajax update="toUpdate">

<h:panelGroup id="toUpdate">

    <p:dataTable id="tableID" rendered="#{bean.someCondition>"...

</h:panelGroup>
```

So, if you have a component that can be o or not visible, do not use it for update, because can be out of components tree. Instead, use a component (container) that your are sure that be rendered and present in the components tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <f:ajax render="toUpdate">

    <h:outputText id="toUpdate">

      <!--  do something -->

    </h:outputText>
```

Comment: Your answer is almost identical to the other one but you want to nest things (components?) inside an `h:outputText`. That is not a good suggestion.